# Comparing quantile regression procedures in R for Panel data (viz. lqmm() and rqpd())

Tags: r, panel, quantile

For a given panel data quantile regression problem with fixed effects (see e.g. below), is it possible to make `lqmm()` output exactly (or at least closely) match the  output from `rqpd()`?

Please see the example below and the conclusions/comments that follow. Am I right in my conclusions?

```
library(lqmm)
library(rqpd)

set.seed(10)
     m <- 3
     n <- 10
     s <- as.factor(rep(1:n,rep(m,n)))
     x <- exp(rnorm(n*m))
     u <- x*rnorm(m*n) + (1-x)*rf(m*n,3,3)
     a <- rep(rnorm(n),rep(m,n))
     y <- rep(1:n,rep(m,n)) + u 
 #    fit <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 5))

data1<-data.frame(y,x,s)
fit.lqmm<- lqmm(fixed=y~x ,  random=~1, group=s, iota=.5,nK=2000, type="normal", rule=1, covariance="pdIdent", data=data1)
coef(fit.lqmm)
ss1<-raneff.lqmm(fit.lqmm)

sig2<-cov.lqmm(fit.lqmm)
sig2


fit.rqpd <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 1/2*1/sig2,taus=.5, method="pfe", tauw=1))
coef(fit.rqpd)

# comparing estimated fixed effects
ss2<-coef(fit.rqpd)[3:length(coef(fit.rqpd))]
plot(as.matrix(ss1),as.numeric(ss2))
```

## Conclusions/comments

1. We expect that for a particular choice of lambda, `rqpd()` should closely match `lqmm()`.  I guess it should be when `lambda=1/(2 cov.lqmm)`. Correct?

   - I am saying close match and not exact because `rqpd` is based on L1 regularization for a fixed lambda, while I think (??) `lqmm` is based on L2 regularization but for a specific lambda that results from the procedure in Geraci and Bottai (2007).
2. At the outset this does not happen at least when nK is small, i.e. say nK=7. But as nK increases to say 100 or 1000, these two procedures "seem" to get close
3. So it appears as if the appropriate use of `lqmm` would at least depend on a good (perhaps large enough) choice of nK.
4. I was exploring the use of `lqmm()` because here the penalty parameter is chosen systematically whereas in `rqpd()` it needs to be supplied. However, since I am not able to match `lqmm()` with `rqpd` for a particular choice of lambda, I am not sure I understand what `lqmm` is doing.